# Build an app on Chrome browser e not with the stock android browser?

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, web-worker

I'm developing an app with phonegap on Android.
The stock browser on Android not support "Web Worker" while Chrome support it.
My question is:
is it possible build my app with eclipse directly with Chrome browser and not with the stock android browser?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. Please see the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq):

> Q: Does Chrome for Android now support the embedded WebView for a hybrid native/web app?
>
> A: We are evaluating ways we can support WebView with Chrome but do not have any plans to announce at this time.

Comment: Thanks.It's a really big problem for developers that want develop an hybrid App with concurrence problem because web-worker of HTML5 doesn't work for stock android browser...

Comment: I agree, I am excited with this new possibility.

Answer (score 0):

This is loosely related - I believe - to this question: [Package Chrome browser into a HTML5 Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409294/package-chrome-browser-into-a-html5-android-app)

The Crosswalk project *might* be of interest to you.