# Package Chrome browser into a HTML5 Android app

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, cordova

We're developing several HTML5 apps based on the Sencha framework, and thinking about packaging them into apps with say PhoneGap.

However, even if you package these into apps, I'm assuming you still have to deal with the Android fragmentation with various manufacturers making weird modifications to the browser. We've tested a lot of manufacturers (especially those from China) and the default Android browser is being hacked to death.

Our app works perfectly in the Chrome browser on Android, so, the question is, is it possible to just literally put Chrome into the same package and just use that? Instead of some random modified browsers each manufacturer feels like making.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, still very new to this. Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming you still have to deal with the Android fragmentation with various manufacturers making weird modifications to the browser

PhoneGap doesn't use the browser. PhoneGap uses a Web rendering engine per platform. On Android, that is `WebView`. Hence, it matters not a whit what manufacturers do the the AOSP Browser application.

> is it possible to just literally put Chrome into the same package and just use that?

If you have a dozen or so Java and Android native code engineers who are capable of taking [the Android build of Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions) and rewriting substantial amounts of Apache Cordova (a.k.a., PhoneGap) to use Chromium, it's at least conceivable. Then again, if you have a dozen or so Java and Android native code engineers, you might be better served simply writing a native Android app, as it will be smaller, faster, and easier to maintain than your own home-grown edition of "ChromiumGap".

To quote the [Chrome for Android FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq):

> **Does Chrome for Android now support the embedded WebView for a hybrid native/web app?**
>
> We are evaluating ways we can support WebView with Chrome but do not have any plans to announce at this time.

Comment: Wait, so what you're saying is, doesn't matter what the manufacturer does tot he default browser, the "WebView" component remains un-corrupted?

Comment: @reedvoid: "Didn't know PhoneGap actually provided a rendering engine, that's awesome" -- that is not what I wrote. The second word in "PhoneGap uses a Web rendering engine per platform" is **"uses"**, not **"provides"**. `WebView` is a standard Android class for rendering Web content, using WebKit under the covers.

Comment: @reedvoid: "doesn't matter what the manufacturer does tot he default browser, the "WebView" component remains un-corrupted?" -- that's certainly not assured. It would depend upon the nature of the "weird modifications to the browser" and whether, to achieve those "weird modifications", they wound up hacking on WebKit or `WebView`. My point simply was that PhoneGap does not use the "browser" (the application). My bigger point was that trying to meld Chromium into Cordova is likely to be much more complicated than simply writing your app as a regular Android app.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the detailed explanation. I guess the only way I'll know for sure how "hacked" these phones are is to try it.

Answer (score 4):

I want to point out Crosswalk: https://crosswalk-project.org/

It seems to provide what you require.

> What is Crosswalk for?
>
> If you are a developer working with web technologies, Crosswalk enables you to deploy a web application with its own dedicated runtime (ed: modified Chromium). This means three things:
>
> - You can distribute your web application via app stores.
> - Your application won't break in whatever ancient webviews or browsers your audience is using, as you control the runtime and its upgrade cycle.
> - You can build applications without worrying so much about runtime differences and quirks: you only have one runtime to deal with.